# Cannot get to bind Enter to 'newline-and-indent in Emacs !!! Very annoying

Tags: emacs

Cannot get to bind Enter to `newline-and-indent` in Emacs !!! Very annoying.

I already tried everything on the following thread by changing 'mode' to ruby and still nothing:

[How do I make Emacs auto-indent my C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823745/how-do-i-make-emacs-auto-indent-my-c-code)

I know that the problem is the <kbd>RETURN</kbd> key, since if I bind to something else, works fine.
I tried `[enter]`, `(kbd "enter")`, `(read-kbd-macro "enter")`, `(kbd "RET")`

---

Follow-up 1.

This is what I get from <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

> RET runs the command newline, which is an interactive compiled Lisp
>   function.
>
> It is bound to RET.
>
> (newline &optional ARG)
>
> Insert a newline, and move to left margin of the new line if it's blank.
>   If `use-hard-newlines' is non-nil, the newline is marked with the
>   text-property`hard'.
>   With ARG, insert that many newlines.
>   Call `auto-fill-function' if the current column number is greater
>   than the value of`fill-column' and ARG is nil.

I dont know what to make of it or how to figure out if it's a global
or local binding that gets in the way. trying to remap <kbd>C-j</kbd>
also doesnt work.

Comment: It might help if you post exactly what customizations you have tried, rather than pointing at another post and saying you changed the mode to ruby.  Probably there is a problem in that last step, but without seeing exactly what you mean, it is difficult to say.

Comment: this works:
(global-set-key [(control x)(control y)] 'newline-and-indent)
<there is a new line here that stackoverflow doesnt show>
this doesn't:
(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)

Comment: Maybe you load some mode that rebinds RET? Try C-h k and press Enter.

Comment: So why don't you try `[(control j)]`?

Comment: Could you please show us exactly what you've added to your init file, and also what `C-u M-x version` reports?

Comment: so (control j) worked fine, although I dont see the connection between j and the Enter key??

Comment: `j` is the 10th letter of the alphabet, so `C-j` is ASCII control character 10, which is the line feed character. In Unix systems, line feed is used as the newline marker, and consequently in some terminals `RET` and `C-j` would be equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a previous comment says, use <kbd>C-h k</kbd> (describe-key) to see what the key is bound to at the point when it's not doing what you want. The `(kbd "foo")` syntax will be correct for whichever `foo` describe-key refers to it as.

Chances are that you are simply not defining that key in the appropriate keymap.

Note that major and minor mode keymaps take precedence over the global keymap, so you shouldn't necessarily be surprised if a global binding is overridden.

edit:

Myself, I have a hook function for common behaviours for all the programming modes I use, and it includes the sort of remapping you're after. The relevant part looks like this:

```
(defun my-coding-config ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") (key-binding (kbd "M-j")))
  (local-set-key (kbd "<S-return>") 'newline)
  )

(mapc
 (lambda (language-mode-hook)
   (add-hook language-mode-hook 'my-coding-config))
 '(cperl-mode-hook
   css-mode-hook
   emacs-lisp-mode-hook
   ;; etc...
   ))
```

See Daimrod's answer for the explanation of why I'm re-binding <kbd>RET</kbd> to the current binding of <kbd>M-j</kbd> -- although I'm using `comment-indent-new-line` (or similar) instead of `newline-and-indent` (or similar), which does what I want in both comments and non-comments.

In Emacs 24, programming modes seem to derive from `prog-mode`, so you could *probably* (un-tested) reduce that list to `prog-mode-hook` plus any exceptions for third-party modes which don't yet do that.

Answer (score 2):

As said earlier, use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> because
<kbd>C-j</kbd> is the standard key to do `newline-and-indent`.

If you open a new file, activate `ruby-mode` and try the previous
command you will see why it doesn't work. Because `ruby-mode` doesn't
have `newline-and-indent` but rather
`reindent-then-newline-and-indent`. Yes that's stupid but you can either ask
to the maintener to change it, or accept it.

However I suggest you to use <kbd>C-j</kbd> to do it because
`ruby-mode` is not the only mode to do so, like `paredit-mode` which
uses `paredit-newline`.