# Emacs indentation

Tags: c, emacs, cc-mode

In Emacs, the line gets indented only after hitting return (in cc-mode). Is that normal? Can that be changed to indent automatically when it hits a new line?

How do I look at variables, for example `There are a number of predefined styles. Take a look at the variable ‘c-style-alist’ to see a list of them.`?

Comment: Type `C-h C-h` to see a list of all the standard help bindings. `C-h` is the standard prefix binding for help functions, and in general you can type `C-h` after a prefix key to get a list of all bindings using that prefix. (In this case you can also use `C-h ?`, but the other pattern is generally useful to know.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in all of my programming mode hooks i have this line:

```
(local-set-key [return] 'newline-and-indent)
```

if for example, you wanted this in all "c" like modes, you would add this to your .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key [return] 'newline-and-indent)))
```

Second question:

to describe something, you would use the help command.  "v" gets help on variables, so you would use: <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>help</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>

Comment: Where do I add that? In preferences --> languages --> C?

Comment: `help v` does not exist. I only do `help-quit` and all commands follow `help` with a dash `-`.

Comment: those are 3 separate key sequences.  type M-x, then type "help" (hit enter), then type `v`.

Comment: Or just use `C-h` `v` variable `RET`.

Comment: You might find `indent-new-comment-line` preferable to `newline-and-indent`, as that does the same thing outside of comments, but continues the comment when you are inside one (which I like). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9060267/324105

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, M-x electric-indent-mode should do the trick.